# Working with coordinates in CodeIgniter 4 (or PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, coordinates

I am programming in CodeIgniter 4, and I don't know how to deal with the following problem using either CodeIgniter 4 or directly with PHP.

I have a database table `places` with one column `coord` with the position (coordinates) of each place, a MySQL column of type `point`. Thanks to CodeIgniter 4 I get all the columns, but in order to use the latitude and longitude separately I need to do:

```
select (*, st_x(coord) as lat, st_y(coord) as lon)
from ...
```

That way, I can use `lat` and `lon`. If I just use `coord` I get something without meaning.

Is there a way to do one of the following:

1. Work with that `coord` variable to get the latitude and longitude in PHP?
2. Add a function in the MySQL table to make that select(*) return also the lat and lon columns (calculated from `st_x(coord)` and `st_y(coord)`)?

Comment: can you add an example of a `coord`?

Comment: `coord` is a `point`, a particular kind of `geometry`, as defined in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-class-point.html

Comment: I know that, just wanted to check if you might eventually have the wrong data there :) sorry, but stranger things have happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add [virtual generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) for lat and lon -

```
ALTER TABLE places
    ADD COLUMN lat DOUBLE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ST_X(coord)) VIRTUAL,
    ADD COLUMN lon DOUBLE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ST_Y(coord)) VIRTUAL;
```

Comment: Thank you! And I am sure that select * will also return this values which is what I want. Great!